# Can't bind to 'gridOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'ag-grid-angular' (Angular4)

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I have this code in HTML:

```
<ag-grid-angular [gridOptions]="gridOptions"></ag-grid-angular>
```

code in Component:

```
import {GridOptions} from 'ag-grid'; 
...

export class SampleComponent{
   gridOptions: GridOptions;
}
...
```

app.module.ts:

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {AgGridModule} from "ag-grid-angular/main";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
...

@NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports: [
        ...
        AgGridModule.withComponents([])
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

What can be the source for the error that I get?
Here is the full error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind
>   to 'gridOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'ag-grid-angular'.
>
> 1. If 'ag-grid-angular' is an Angular component and it has 'gridOptions' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'ag-grid-angular' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>      to suppress this message.

Comment: can you post your app.module.ts

Comment: Possible duplicate of (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44238887/9775003)

Comment: @Sanoj_V The solution is that question does not solve my problem. I already have `AgGridModule.withComponents([])` in imports.

Comment: @Sajeetharan Yes, I have added the app.module.ts

Comment: I don't know whether this will help, but in my class that uses `ag-grid` I have the following import: `import { AgGridNg2 } from 'ag-grid-angular';` (I don't have the import of `AgGridModule`).

Answer (score 0):

Try to initiatlize gridOptions as follows and see

```
constructor() {
    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
    this.columnDefinitions = [

    ];

    this.gridOptions = {
      columnDefs: this.columnDefinitions,
      enableFilter: true,
      enableSorting: true,
      pagination: true
    };

    this.rowSelection = 'single';
  }
```

**EDIT**

Your actual issue is here, Change

From

```
<ag-grid-angular [gridOptions]="gridOptions"></ag-grig-angular>
```

To

```
<ag-grid-angular [gridOptions]="gridOptions"></ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't work :(

Comment: oh that is very strange! can i see your complete code

Comment: may I know what versions you are using? In case it has to do with the version.

Comment: its not a verison issue, its a spelling issue, check the edited answer

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. I mistyped it. So, I last tried to remove the `[gridOptions]...` all together and I got an error: `ag-grid-angular' is not a known element`

Comment: what is the component name?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a grid without gridOptions as well in your cae. Please find below the complete code:-

```
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 500px;height: 200px;" class="ag-theme-balham" [animateRows]="true" [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [enableSorting]="true" [enableFilter]="true" (gridReady)="OnGridReady($event)">
```